# Google apps scripts: regexmatch based on two criteria including a passed variable

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

I’m using `SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenFormulaSatisfied()` to filter a sheet, but I’m not getting the regexmatch() function setup properly. I need to filter column A based on two criteria:

1. must contain “ak1” or “ak2”
2. And, must contain `myVar` which is a variable that will be passed to the script.

I know how to write the `regexmatch` statement to get criteria 1 (`regexmatch(A:A, "(?i)ak1|ak2")`), but I’m getting stuck on how to combine that with criteria 2.

My best attempt so far:

```
var regex = new RegExp( myVar, 'g' );
var crit = '=regexmatch(A:A, "^(?=.*ak1|ak2|)(?=.*myVar)")'
```

Edited to add example:

If col A contains

```
Chr_rq_ak1
Chr_rq_ak2
Chr_rq_ak6
Chr_gv_ak1
```

I would expect the following to be visible and the remainder hidden:

```
Chr_rq_ak1
Chr_rq_ak2
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of sheet name?

Comment: I think the pattern should be `^(?=.*ak[12])(?=.*myVar)` See https://regex101.com/r/Pr2V8c/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use `AND`:

```
=AND(REGEXMATCH(A2,"(?i)ak(?:1|2)"),REGEXMATCH(A2,"myVar"))
```

Comment: I wasn't able to get the other answer to work. I was able to get this suggestion to work with a little modification: `var crit = '=AND(REGEXMATCH(A2, "(?i)ak(?:1|2)"),REGEXMATCH(A2,"'+myVar+'"))'` where `var myVar = "rq"`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the alternation you have to group them`(?=.*(?:k1|ak2))` and leave out the `|` at the end.

If you have only a single char following, you could also use a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

```
^(?=.*ak[12])(?=.*myVar)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Pr2V8c/1)